# How do I spawn an item using Random.Range, but have the waiting time change after each spawn?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

My concept is very simple: I am spawning objects. I have three floats: RunEvery, BetweenThis, and AndThis. I can get a value in return, but I am unable to change this value. I'd like a new random number every time, but I just keep getting the same initial value.

```
RunEvery = Random.Range(BetweenThis, AndThis);
```

Let's say that BetweenThis is equal to 1, and AndThis is equal to 20. RunEvery then becomes any number between 1 and 20. So if the chosen number is 10, the script will spawn that object every ten seconds.

I'm not looking for, "10, 10, 10, 10, 10...etc."

I need, "10, 7, 5.5, 18, 9...etc."

```
public UnityEvent OnTimerEnd;

void OnEnable()
{
    SetRandomizer();
    if (RunOnAwake){
        Invoke("Execute", 0);
    }
    if (Loop){
        //SetRandomizer();
        InvokeRepeating("Execute", RunEvery, RunEvery);
    }
    else{
        Invoke("Execute", RunEvery);
    }
}

public void SetRandomizer(){
    RunEvery = Random.Range(BetweenThis, AndThis);
    Debug.Log("The Random Range is " + RunEvery);
}

public void Execute(){
    OnTimerEnd.Invoke();
    //SetRandomizer();
}
```

I'd like it to keep choosing random numbers, but I can only get the script to repeat the initial value every single time.

I've tried creating new functions that hold the Random.Range stuff, but for some reason, it will only even use that first generated value.

I've tried moving parts of the code around, creating an IEnumerator and just waiting, and I even tried turning the entire script on and off. There's a bunch of other stuff I tried, but I won't bore you with that.

I'm sure it's a simple thing to fix, but it's just not something I can figure out on my own. I looked through the Scripting API and the manual and my C# books, but they only ever talk about using Random.Range only once, not repeatedly.

Comment: So just to be clear,suppose say the first value you get i.e RunEvery say 10 after 10sec you want to spawn the objects and at that time also you want new value assigned to RunEvery correct ?

Comment: @PraveenPanishetti, Yes. For example, let's say we have a drop of water falling from a leaf. The first random number is a range between 1 and 20 seconds. Let's say it randomly chooses the number 5. After 5 seconds, the drop of rain would spawn and fall. A new random number between 1 and 20 is chosen. Let's say it randomly chooses 17 seconds. 17 seconds after the first drop, the second drop will fall. A new random number will be chosen, and the drops will continue in this manner. Currently, I can only retain the use of the initial calculation, even if I reset the value.

Answer (score 2):

`Random.Range` gives you an `int` that doesn't change after you generate it. For example:

```cs
int rand = Random.Range(0, 10);
Debug.Log(rand); // 4
```

`rand` is a variable that holds the value 4. It doesn't hold the code to generate another random number. You have to run Random.Range() again if you want to make a new random number. In your code above you're only storing the result of the random number and using it over and over again.

Additionally, `InvokeRepeating()` will use the same number you supply to it for each subsequent invocation. You need to call `Invoke()` manually with a different number each time if you want it to be random.

You can nest it as an easy way to loop the invocation:

```cs
void Start
{
     Invoke("Execute", 0);
}

void Execute()
{
      float randTime = Random.Range(your min, your max )

      // do you code

      if (Loop)
          Invoke("Execute", randTime);

}
```